# PowerShell set path variable

Tags: powershell

Trying to set a path variable inside another set:

```
$e = Get-Content c:\path\foo.txt
$f = "$e\folder\folder"
```

This is an attempt to `robocopy` something later like

```
robocopy $f $g /MIR
```

Thoughts or suggestions on this?

Comment: Are you getting an error or something? What is the content of foo.txt?

Comment: the error is on the robocopy its not finding either source or dest.

if i write-host $e the path is correct

Comment: haha gramatical error on my part diregard